# Splitting an equation into multiple lines

Tags: equations, line-breaking

I want to display the following equation:

[image]

The LaTeX code I have made is as follows:

```
\[PaD^{i}=\left [ \frac{(1-\frac{n_{1}}{N})\times M(i,1)}{m}+\frac{\sum_{t=2}^{m}[(1-\frac{n_{t}}{N}\times \frac{n_{t-1}}{N})\times M(i,t)\times M(i,t-1) )]}{m}+\\ \frac{\sum_{t=2}^{m}[(1-\frac{n_{t}}{N}\times \frac{N-n_{t-1}}{N})\times M(i,t)\times (1-M(i,t-1))]}{m}\right ]\times 100\%\]
```

Is there any way to break the right side of the equation into three lines so that it can fit the page?

Answer (score 2):

Here are two possible solutions. The first is kind of minimal, in that it uses an `align*` environment and provides for two line breaks. (Well, I also replace most instances of `\times` with `\cdot`, and I eliminated a spurious `)` in the middle row.)

The second solution goes further towards making it easy on your reader to actually *read* and comprehend the material. E.g., by writing `\frac{1}{m}` at the beginning of each of the three additive terms, the remaining material can be typeset using larger lettering. After all, the material that's being summed up is at least as important as the `\frac{1}{m}` term, right? The second solution also gets rid of all `\cdot` directives and places the `100\%` block at the start, to give it more visual prominence.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' env.

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\mathit{PaD}^{i}
&=\biggl[ \frac{(1-\frac{n_{1}}{N})\cdot M(i,1)}{m}\\
&\qquad+\frac{\sum_{t=2}^{m}[(1-\frac{n_{t}}{N}\cdot \frac{n_{t-1}}{N})\cdot M(i,t)\cdot M(i,t-1) ]}{m}\\ 
&\qquad+\frac{\sum_{t=2}^{m}[(1-\frac{n_{t}}{N}\cdot \frac{N-n_{t-1}}{N})\cdot M(i,t)\cdot (1-M(i,t-1))]}{m}
\biggr] \times 100\,\% 
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\mathit{PaD}^{i}
=100\,\% \times \biggl\{ \phantom{{}+{}}
&\frac{1}{m}\Bigl(1-\frac{n_{1}}{N}\Bigr) M(i,1)\\
+{}&\frac{1}{m}\sum_{t=2}^{m}\Bigl[\Bigl(1-\frac{n_{t}}{N} \frac{n_{t-1}}{N}\Bigr) M(i,t) M(i,t-1) \Bigr]\\ 
+{}&\frac{1}{m}\sum_{t=2}^{m}\Bigl[\Bigl(1-\frac{n_{t}}{N} \frac{N-n_{t-1}}{N}\Bigr) M(i,t) (1-M(i,t-1)) \Bigr]
\biggr\}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course, one could take the `\frac{1}{m}` term *outside* the curly braces. However, I didn't go that far since I don't know if the *meaning* of the three additive terms depends on them being scaled by `\frac{1}{m}`. For sure, additive terms 2 and 3 seem to be some kind of average...

Comment: While I am trying to use \begin{align*} \end{align*} inside \begin{equation} \end{equation} block, I am getting error @Mico

Comment: @user5411115 - Well, you *must not* nest these two particular environments. If want to create a nested structure, use `split` as the inner environment.

Comment: @user5411115 - If you want to become a proficient user of LaTeX and writer of mathy material, you should take the time to study the user guide of the `ansmath` package.

Comment: is there any way to create an equation number using the approach you have shown? @Mico

Comment: @user5411115 -- if you want a single equation number, then substitute `aligned` for `align*` and wrap the whole thing in `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}`.  (in this situation, `aligned` is very similar to `split`, which Mico has already suggested.)

Comment: @user5411115 - Use `equation` as the outer environment and `split` (or `aligned` -- see barbara's comment) as the inner environment.